# Access: Change select to delete query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am sure this is an easy fix however it is baffling me at the moment – basically I want to change this query into a delete query

```
SELECT Raw_Log_Import_List.File_URL
FROM Imported_Log_List, Raw_Log_Import_List
WHERE ((Mid([Imported_Log_List].[File_URL],InStrRev([Imported_Log_List].[File_URL],"\")+1)= Mid([Raw_Log_Import_List].[File_URL],InStrRev([Raw_Log_Import_List].[File_URL],"\")+1)));
```

However when I try to run it as a delete I get a `specify table` `error – specifying the table [Raw_Log_Import_List] then generates a syntax error`

I have tried running this as a subquery – see below

```
DELETE Raw_Log_Import_List.File_URL, *
FROM Raw_Log_Import_List
WHERE (((Raw_Log_Import_List.File_URL)=(SELECT Raw_Log_Import_List.File_URL
FROM Imported_Log_List, Raw_Log_Import_List
WHERE ((Mid([Imported_Log_List].[File_URL],InStrRev([Imported_Log_List].[File_URL],"\")+1)= Mid([Raw_Log_Import_List].[File_URL],InStrRev([Raw_Log_Import_List].[File_URL],"\")+1)));)));
```

However this generates a `at most one record can be returned..` error.

I know I could solve this issue by creating another couple of calculated fields for the string manipulations however, I am keen to learn how to make this work with either a conventional delete or a sub query

Cheers for your help as ever guys

Comment: Do you want to delete whole row or only update File_URL ??

Answer (score 0):

improved formatting If you want to delete whole row is should be like

```
DELETE FROM Raw_Log_Import_List
WHERE (((Raw_Log_Import_List.File_URL)= 
 ( 
   SELECT Raw_Log_Import_List.File_URL
   FROM Imported_Log_List, Raw_Log_Import_List
   WHERE ((Mid([Imported_Log_List].[File_URL],InStrRev([Imported_Log_List].
   [File_URL],"\")+1)= Mid([Raw_Log_Import_List].[File_URL],
   InStrRev([Raw_Log_Import_List].[File_URL],"\")+1)));)
  ));
```

Comment: OK - many thanks for getting back - so i tried running this however, I get the 'query must have at least one destination field' error - how do I correct this?

Comment: aaaa got it - the subquery is returning more than one record -there fore it will not compile - back to the drawing board on that one then....